# How to validate time range so that end date cannot be before today?

Tags: flutter

I can select a date range but I'd like to validate the end date, it cannot be before today.

This selection shouldn't be possible:

[image]

```
dateTimeRangePicker() async {
    final dateRange = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 10),
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      initialDateRange: fromDate != null
          ? DateTimeRange(start: fromDate!, end: toDate!)
          : null,
    );
    if (dateRange is DateTimeRange) {
      setState(() {
        fromDate = dateRange.start;
        toDate = dateRange.end;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: "If initialDateRange is non-null, then it will be used as the initially selected date range. If it is provided, initialDateRange.start must be before or on initialDateRange.end."
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDateRangePicker.html

Does is allow you to select an end date that is before the start date?

Comment: But that mentions start and end. The second one is always after but I'm talking about today's date. The end date should be after that one only.
I guess that's a custom validation but I'm not sure how to check it before leaving the calendar. I could do a simple check at the end of the process and force the user to come back and change the date range but I want to know if is possible to validate this directly from the calendar itself without leaving this component (to have a better UX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to validate date range you want in calendar view. You can do something like this

```
dateTimeRangePicker() async {
    final dateRange = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 10),
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
    if (dateRange is DateTimeRange) {
      setState(() {
        fromDate = dateRange.start;
        if (dateRange.end.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
          //change it as your wish
          toDate = DateTime.now();
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text("Invalid Date Range!"),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          toDate = dateRange.end;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: fair enough. That was my first idea but wanted to double check

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this

here is the code

```
  datePicker() async {
    DateTimeRange picked = (await showDateRangePicker(
        context: context,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
        //last date by subtracting 1 ensures it cannot be before today.
        lastDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
        initialDateRange: DateTimeRange(
          end: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
          start: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7)),
        ),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: 400.0,
                ),
                child: child,
              )
            ],
          );
        }))!;
    print(picked.start);
    print(picked.end);
    //proceed to do something with the daterange
  }
```

[image: result]

Comment: why do you have `lastDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1))`? That will block all days from tomorrow

Comment: from your question, i cannot be before today, i understood this as must be past date. Not a future date or todays date

Comment: I'm talking only about end date. Start date shouldn't be validated